# How to set "Advertising Features" and other settings through Google Analytics Management API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Management API to automate the management of a large amount of GA Properties, which is what it's for according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3#intro).

However, I'm having trouble with a lot of settings, that it seems like are not available through the API. The [expected format](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource) of a GA property resource is quite limited in the fields you can set, and it seems to not allow specifying other fields.

Specifically, I am interested in setting the "Advertising features", aka whether to enable the Demographics and Interest Reports:

[image: Advertising features setting in Google Analytics]

When updating this setting through the GA UI, the field within the request seems to be called `demographicsEnabled`, but I cannot set or retrieve this value when using the Management API.

How can I set this and other values through the Management API, or other means? If only a small fraction of the settings for a property can be set through the API, that seems kinda useless for managing large accounts, as the docs claim you can do - so I assume there has to be a way I'm just not seeing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I set this and other values through the Management API, or other means?

You cant the management api is very limited in what fields you are able to update.  Unfortunately unlike a number of other google apis documentation it doesn't actually tell you which fields are writeable.  I will mention that to the team.

> If only a small fraction of the settings for a property can be set through the API, that seems kinda useless for managing large accounts, as the docs claim you can do - so I assume there has to be a way I'm just not seeing here.

The API was not intended for managing large accounts IMO.  It was probably only intended for getting information about what accounts a current user has access to.

What i suggest that you do is create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400) asking for the ability to update the fields that you are trying to update.  The team is normally very open to those types of requests.

Link it here and i will be happy to bring it to the teams attention next time i speak with them.

Comment: Thanks - sad to hear that this is not possible ATM. I will collect a list of fields we need to set and will open a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this and many other features are not available in Management API.

Comment: And there's no *other* way either?